# can´t PUT with node.js

Tags: node.js, post, handlebars.js, http-status-code-404, put

I keep getting a `Cannot POST /discos/edit/` message, with a 404 error at my terminal.
I can´t seem to find the correct path, as i believe it may be a URL error somewhere i can´t find.

Thanks for your help.

My code:

```
`router.get(`/discos/edit/:id`, editRecord)`


discosCtrl.editRecord = async (req, res) => {
const disco = await DiscoSchema.findById(req.params.id).lean()
//console.log(disco)
res.render(`discos/edit-record`, {disco})
}`
```

This get method works fine.

Then, this is my PUT method, where i can´t post the info i´ve received from my previous GET request.

```
`router.put(`/discos/edit/:id`, updateRecord)`

`discosCtrl.updateRecord =  (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body)
}`
```

My Html line, where i override the POST method:

```
<form action="/discos/edit/{{disco.id}}?_method=PUT" method="POST"> 
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

`
Thanks for your help.

I can´t seem to find my mistake. I´m following some tutorial using the same code but they´re succeeding while i´m just getting the same 404 error.

Comment: Are you using middleware that allows the URL appended with `_method=PUT` to be handled as a PUT instead of a POST?

Comment: yes, method override.

Comment: Are you including an `id` in your POST request URL? You stated that your error says "Cannot POST /discos/edit/", but your URL should be like `/discos/edit/100`.